# Jasper Reports on CentOS Server acting strange

Tags: command-line-interface, systempath

So I added Jasper to my classpath, got Apache ant installed and everything seems fine. I went to hsqldb directory and run "ant runServer" & "ant runManager" and both started up. I went to a sample report and ran "ant -p" and it gave me syntax errors, it did not generate the report correctly. That is problem #1. Problem #2 is soon after I tried that, I went back into hsqldb and did the "ant runServer"/"ant runManager" commands, and it shoots out "-bash: ant: command not found" - I restarted the server, which is Linux, and still have the same problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue an `whereis ant`. If it can't find ant, then it is not installed in a location in your PATH.

If it is not installed in a directory in the PATH then either add this location to your PATH or try to execute ant with full path like `/usr/local/bin/ant runServer`.

Comment: Wow, thank you! It is working great when I type out the entire path to ant. It even worked when I went into "table" demo and did the ant -p, it generated the report no problem. The question now is, am I am set? Say I have PHP linked to generate reports, all I have to do is make sure the path to run the commands are specified?

Comment: I would say yes. If you get an error post a NEW question with detailed problem description.